# 503 - Service unavailable message - querying ravenDB

Tags: asp.net, linq, nosql, ravendb

I am getting "503 - service unavailable" error message while querying ravenDB.

Code:

```
    //A

    CalcModel.MoviesByCertDt = session.Query<Movies>()
                               .Where(x => x.CertDate.Date == d2.Date)
                               .Count();
    //B

    CalcModel.MoviesByReleaseDt = session.Query<Movies>()
                                .Where(x => x.ReleaseDate.Value.Date == d2.Date)
                                .Count();
```

A works well. B gives me "InavalidOperationException" - "The service is unavailable" 
{"The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."}

In the model, the two fields are defined as :

```
     public DateTime CertDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

d2.date is the parameter for the MVC controller thats coming from the user input. I cannot change the data type of DateTime? for ReleaseDate. It has to be "DateTime?" type. I tried doing

```
  CalcModel.MoviesByReleaseDt = session.Query<Movies>()
                            .Where(x => x.ReleaseDate != null && 
                                        x.ReleaseDate.Value.Date == d2.Date)
                            .Count();
```

But still get the same error message. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cross posting. This is being discussed in the products mailing list.

Comment: Still unresolved. Its something to do with the ReleaseDate that is of type "DateTime?" .. as this does not happen if I swap ReleaseDate with CertDate which if of type "DateTime".. If any one has any insight or suggestions, please post. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this'll help (since it's similar to what you've already tried), but have you tried changing

```
.Where(x => x.ReleaseDate.Value.Date == d2.Date)
```

to

```
.Where(x => x.ReleaseDate.HasValue && x.ReleaseDate.Value.Date == d2.Date)
```